# Mind maps of Advanced Mathematics and various branches thereof

Tags: big-list, education

I would like to get a list of mind maps of advanced mathematics topics. As an example, I have posted one [below](http://space.mit.edu/home/tegmark/toe.gif). I would be happy if you post such other maps. Making one and posting it here is also encouraged.

However, I am specifically not interested in those diagrams that pertain to either high school mathematics or an intricate web of highly specialized theorems. 
[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tick the Community Wiki box. And now, the box does not show when I try to edit.

Comment: Not sure how you are using the words, "mind map," but Wikipedia says "... items linked to and arranged around a central key word or idea."  Here, do you really want "formal systems" to be your "central key idea?"  This seems like an unproductive use of a mind map

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, how about "Visual aids" or "Visual maps"?

Comment: There is a table at the beginning of the book Abstract Algebra: an introduction by Thomas W. Hungerford resulting in a mental map of abstract basic Algebra as it is this that you want.I hope helped in your search.

Comment: Do you know other sites with these mental maps math?

Comment: @Elias, I just saw the map you referred to in Hungerford. It seems to me that the map there is not as structured, branching out at an increasing level of specialization as the one I posted above. I saw one other but I do not remember where.

Comment: The table that Elias mentions from  Abstract Algebra: an introduction by Thomas W. Hungerford can be found on-line here:
http://i.imgur.com/lCMlb.png

(Taken from here: http://www.scribd.com/doc/47153639/Abstract-Algebra-An-Introduction-Thomas-W-Hungerford)

Comment: Awesome map! I was mulling over this same idea a few days ago. I would like to contribute with Computer Science "side" of Mathematics. It will take a few days to get it together properly for me, but I hope to have something by then to share.

Comment: The term "abelian fields" in that diagram is bizarre. *Nobody* uses it. The term "metric manifolds" also seems odd; semi-Riemannian manifolds is more common.

Comment: When seeing the term "mind map", is anyone else reminded of the idea of a "map of the cat" from Feynman's SYJMF?

Comment: @KCd, thank you for the comments.

Comment: @KCd: I wonder if the metric manifolds case is supposed to also include stuff like Finsler manifolds?

Comment: @WillieWong, thanks for helping to make the post CW. But I do not know why I did not lose the points I earned for this post before it was made CW.

Comment: @Chulumba: short answer is: you don't. Points earned prior to CW-fication are always kept. Don't worry too much about it. `:-)`

Comment: @WillieWong, thank you for the reply. I will be happy!

Comment: @WillieWong, my problem is exactly being discussed here:http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1336/chrome-crash/#Item_0 I am using Chrome on Windows and the tick box did not show when I clicked on 'edit' under my question.

Comment: @Chulumba: on the StackExchange2 network (of which Math.SE is a member, but not MathOverflow), users cannot mark their own *questions* CW. (Users can, however, mark their own *answers* CW.)

Comment: @WillieWong, did not know. Thanks.

Comment: This is probably worth a link here: http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/

Comment: @yasmar, right you are.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is a mind map by  [Konrad Voelkel](http://blog.konradvoelkel.de/2011/11/complex-analysis-mindmap/) that I understand and which was quite helpful when I was going to revise for an exam in Complex Analysis.

[image]

And another that is beyond my head presently and probably way beyond this site too `;-)` is the following which appeared [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.0069).(I keep this as a souvenir of how much abstraction there is in mathematics! I hope you would, too.)

[image]

Comment: Do you know which software was used to create the first diagram of your answer ?

Answer (score 11):

Although it is a bit messy, you may be interested in the following map:

[image]

If anyone knows who made it, please let me know!

Comment: Holy hell, did you make that by hand!

Comment: @Arjang no no, I didn't! I found it somewhere on the internet. I think the person who made it, made it by hand though. However, I don't know who the creator of this map is.

Answer (score 10):

Although I do not know whether you call it a mind map or not, [the Periodic Table of Finite Simple Groups](https://irandrus.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/periodic-table-of-groups.pdf) was a recent brainchild of [Ivan Andrus](http://web.ceu.hu/math/People/PhD_Students/Ivan_ANDRUS.html), described in more detail in his [blog post](http://irandrus.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/the-periodic-table-of-finite-simple-groups/).

In picture, here it is:

[image: clickable image]

Answer (score 5):

I just found a fantastic map titled "A Map of the L-functions and Modular Forms Database"  [here](http://www.lmfdb.org/).

The best way to view it including the alt text is by [clicking through](http://www.lmfdb.org/bigpicture) to get to the original website or observe the picture below

[image]

Comment: The image can't be saved with the alternate text. How can I do that so that I can post it here in full detail?

Comment: I've added the picture for you; just took a screensnap of the web page and uploaded that.

Comment: @ItsNotObvious, thanks but did you not miss the alt-text? Perhaps it is not possible to save it that way.

Comment: If you mean the text that shows up when you hover over each element, there is no straightforward way to do this other than to save the html of the page and copy/past the hints to the desired location; they can't be captured as part of the image because only one shows up at a time!

Comment: @ItsNotObvious, okay. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

[The Mathematical atlas](http://www.math-atlas.org/) : A gateway to modern mathematics

Comment: the link is broken =(

Comment: @PtF Here's a cached version from before the Atlas went down: http://web.archive.org/web/20150417125053/http://www.math-atlas.org/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice map of exceptional (aka interesting) symmetry objects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Map of all mathimatics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Pgm.jpg)

source https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmJ-4B-mS-Y