# Does exist any "graph oriented" database for mathematical definitions?

Tags: logic

Let

Def[ termP | termA, termB, ... ]

be a statement defining the mathematical term "termP" by means of those "termA" , "termB" , ...

As example:

Def[ magma | set, binary operation ]

Def[ semigroup | magma, associative binary operation ]

Def[ monoid | semigroup, identy element ]

Def[ quasigroup | magma, division ]

...

Such entities naturally fit in a graph structure having (1) as vertex each of them  and (2) as directed edges the relations among them.

I have been meditating on for a while  about the possibility to store mathematical definitions in a database shaped around the above considerations (that's the reason why I wrote "graph oriented", in the title).

Please, can you point at :
- previous attempts, if any (may be, I'm reinventing the wheel ...)
- what I should to learn, about graphs, before digging further

Here are mentioned many graph database projects but no one seems to be relevant to mathematical definitions storage: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

My personal notebook, [AxiomsOfChoice.org](http://axiomsofchoice.org), is organized this way. 
It's a Doku-Wiki of formal definitions and comments about those entities, and I read out the entries and can plot them in a graph showing requirements for the definitions and subset relations.

For example, [here](http://axiomsofchoice.org/semigroup) is the (short) entry on semigroups. At the bottom it specifies that the Magma entry points at it, and the Monid entry in turn points at Semigroup.
What a "subset" is might depend on the context. E.g. [here](http://axiomsofchoice.org/limit_._category_theory) is the entry on the category theoretical limit, and at at the bottom you learn that in its definition I require the notion of a Functor category, a Diagonal functor, and that it's a Terminal morphism.

A friend helped me to set up a visualization using the free software graph-viz. When I have time, I'll write my own more dynamics version, because at about 70 vertices, the edges starting in an unpractical way, and at 200 vertices, I stopped using it.

I gave an answer on what I found out is already out there [in this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902296/mathematics-the-big-picture/905976#905976). Please comment here/tell me when you find out more about these kinds of things, my project is also always under construction.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I'm browsing your interesting site and I will keep you updated. At present moment I'm evaluating the opportunity to develop a sketchy database in Mathematica.
I'm a newcomer in stackexchange.com community: may I ask what's the appropriate way to debate an issue in terms not immediately answering the question I asked ?

Comment: @user281912: In fact I stated out to generate the graph in Mathematica too, see http://i.imgur.com/GpNymt6.png, but it's not really the appropriate software for either the graph nor the data content behind it. StackExchange isn't really suited for discussions, but you can open up a chat (search for the keyword on the front page) and call people by writing @ and then their name.