# Dependency of mathematical subjects

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

At times a book has a dependency diagram, the order that chapters can be tackled, from chapters that require no other chapters (i.e. the simplest chapters), to chapters that might rely on knowledge of 3,4 other chapters (most complex chapters).

Is there a dependency graph for mathematical subjects? i.e. what subjects $s_1,\cdots s_n$ are needed to be known before subject $t$ can be taken?

Such a dependency would be useful for self study

Comment: You might want to add 'directed' before graph. And mitopencourseware might help you a bit as there is a graph avalaible for subjects in math they offer.

Comment: all the dependencies I know are directed, or do you mean something else?

Comment: https://www.oakton.edu/academics/academic_departments/math/student_resources/mathgraph.pdf might get you started. Or try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879/where-can-i-find-a-math-topic-dependency-tree-to-assist-my-self-guided-refresh or http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?t=69851

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902296 (see the linked questions).