# A map (big picture) of the relationship of all areas in mathematics (including probability, stat, and information theory, etc)

Tags: soft-question, big-picture

Update 10/15:
What I could remember is the picture was under a section named "interesting stuff" (something like this), with a link toward the picture (if I remember it correctly). Also, the professor is Japanese at a University in Japan. I have checked all faculty personal pages in the department of mathematics at following universities and yet found it:

The University of Tokyo

Kyoto University

Kobe University

Tokyo University of Science

In addition, I said the picture is much bigger than the one at https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMquw.jpg , for example, it has items like "random forest", "information theory", and things like xxx palace (can't remember, maybe function palace? topological palace?). In summary, a much much bigger picture (map).

---

Update 10/14:
I am looking for a specific map. But it may not on that professor's website only. He may get it from somewhere else. That map was so beautiful that I regret didn't save it. I believe it also helps others in understanding. I saw that map on his website last year (2018).

---

I am looking for a map (big picture) of the relationship of all areas in mathematics (including probability, stat, and information theory, etc). I saw the map on a homepage of a Japanese professor before but couldn't recall his name nor his university. His map is relatively huge, beautiful, not colorful, with mountains and streams, and rivers. The style looks like this but much bigger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMquw.jpg

I understand the existence of the question at [Mathematics - The big picture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902296/mathematics-the-big-picture)
, but none of the pictures there is the one I was looking for.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the question being so soft!

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for *that specific* map, not just some map?

Comment: Yes, that specific map. But it may not on that professor's website only. He may get it from somewhere else. That map was so beautiful that I regret didn't save it. I believe it also helps others in understanding. Thank you!