# How "big" are the mathematical disciplines?

Tags: soft-question

This question may be difficult to answer, but is it possible to estimate the "size" of the individual mathematical disciplines; measures of size could be number of professionals dealing with it, the number of magazines and new theorems etc.? For instance, I usually consider analysis, algebra, and topology to be the three major branches of mathematics. But how many of the total number of mathematicians are dealing with each of these? My impression is that analysis is the largest discipline, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Although those are traditional labels, it is simply not the case that mathematics is "divided up" in any such fashion, despite "AMS subject classification" and other schemes. There are no worthwhile dividing lines, not even the ever-popular "pure versus applied". Sure, many people realize that they have to figure out some self-labels to apply for grants or to communicate when required to do so in those terms, but even then one is often allowed to designate several "labels", rather than a single one.

Comment: True indeed. But it might still be possible to say something about the sizes of the disciplines, even if the borders between them are not very sharp.

Comment: But part of my point is that I disagree with the notion that these "discipline" labels really refer to anything once one is outside an artificial curricular or other contrived structure. Sure, we can choose to behave as though the curriculum or bureaucratic labels made sense, but that doesn't force them to make genuine sense.

Comment: *How “big” are the mathematical disciplines?* - So is this great and wide sea, wherein are things creeping innumerable, both small and great beasts. There go the ships: there is that leviathan, whom thou hast made to play therein. $($Psalm $104:25-26)$.

Answer (score 5):

For a rough graphical representation see for example [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/index/mathmap.html) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/a-graph-map-of-math-se).

[image]

(Related questions with interesting links can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902296/mathematics-the-big-picture) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18201/some-maps-of-the-land-of-mathematics) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124709/mind-maps-of-advanced-mathematics-and-various-branches-thereof).)

Comment: "The sizes of the bubbles reflect the numbers of papers published in the last two decades in each area."